# Blazor server side SPA: Component state after reloading component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-component, blazor-state-management

The problem is the following: I have a component which holds a table and some searchfields for the table. If I do a search and after that I go to another page and back to the table page, all values of the table component are resetted. Like the component is cleaned up and rerendered.

Is it possible to keep the values after going away from the page and coming back again? So the render tree does not reset its values?

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a StateContainer which is added via Dependency Injection as a Scoped service. This can preserve state as explained in the [Microsoft Documentation - State Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#in-memory-state-container-service-server).